# How can I fade out 1 picture on click and fade in automatically 4 pictures one near each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to click on a picture that I already have and then FadeIn 4 more pictures. Something like a filtering. I am trying to choose concrete as a main category for example and then I want to receive 4 more picture FadeIn with the kilos that the user wants to choose.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".pulse-button").click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('fadeOut');

  });

});

//END BUTTON FADEOUT

$('button').on('click', function() {

  $(this).prop('disabled', true);

}); //END BUTTON DISABLE


  //START OF PLASTER-BOARD FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

  $(".pulse-button").click(function() {

    $("#plasterBoard").fadeToggle("slow", "linear", "complete");

  });

//END OF PLASTER-BOARD FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//START OF BRICK FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

$(".pulse-button").click(function() {

  $("#brick").fadeToggle("slow", "linear", "complete");

});

//END OF BRICK FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//START OF CONCRETE STONE FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

$(".pulse-button").click(function() {

  $("#concreteStone").fadeToggle("slow", "linear", "complete");

});

//END OF CONCRETE STONE FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//START OF CONCRETE STONE FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

$(".pulse-button").click(function() {

  $("#aerateConcrete").fadeToggle("slow", "linear", "complete");

});

//END OF CONCRETE STONE FADE-IN FUNCTIONALITY

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$("#plasterBoard").click(function() {

  $("#plasterBoard").fadeOut(300);
  $("#kilosIcon").fadeIn(300);
  $("#KILOIcon").fadeIn(300);
});

$("#brick").click(function() {

  $("#brick").fadeOut(300);

  $("#kilosIcon").fadeIn(300);

});

$("#concreteStone").click(function() {

  $("#concreteStone").fadeOut(300);

  $("#kilosIcon").fadeIn(300);

});

$("#aerateConcrete").click(function() {

  $("#aerateConcrete").fadeOut(300);

  $("#kilosIcon").fadeIn(300);

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pulse-button {
  transition: all .5s linear;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(232, 76, 61, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e84c3d;
  color: white;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -ms-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.pulse-button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}


/* BACKGROUND */

.hero-image {
  background: url(imgs/sajad-mohammadi-1159479-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  !important position: relative;
}


/*----------*/

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 470;
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#kilosIcon {
  margin-top: 470px;
}

.imgBorder {
  padding: 15px 205px 0 205px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<!-- CC -->

<!-- END OF STYLE -->

<!-- END OF HEAD -->

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// BODY  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

<body>
  <!-- START of BODY -->

  <div>
    <!-- START BUTTON -->

    <button id="pulseButton" class="pulse-button" class="container" style="align-content: center; outline: none;">
    
                <h1>START</h1>
    
                <!-- START BUTTON FADEOUT -->
    
            
    
                <!-- ------------------------END OF LAYER 1 FADE IN PICTURES FUNTIONALITIES ---------------------------- -->
    
            </button>
    <!-- END OF BUTTON FUNCTIONALITIES -->

  </div>
  <!-- END START BUTTON -->

  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

  <div class="hero-image">
    <!-- CONTAINER OF 1st LAYER PICTURES DIV -->

    <img id="kilosIcon" src="imgs/10kilo.png" alt="aerateConcrete" class="imgBorder" style="width:25%; display: none; ">

    <!-- Small IMAGES from Filters -->

    <div class="row">

      <div class="column">
        <!-- PICTURE 1 FADE OUT -->

        <img id="plasterBoard" src="imgs/Plasterboard.jpeg" alt="plasterboard" class="imgBorder" style="width:100%; display: none;">

        <!-- Fading in IMAGES on CLICK OF ANOTHER IMAGE -->


      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <!-- PICTURE 2 FADE OUT -->

        <img id="brick" src="imgs/brick.jpeg" alt="brick" class="imgBorder" style="width:100%; display: none;">

      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <!-- PICTURE 3 FADE OUT -->

        <img id="concreteStone" src="imgs/concrete(stone).jpeg" alt="concreteStone" class="imgBorder" style="width:100%; display: none;">

        <!-- FADING IN IMAGES ON CLICK OF ANOTHER IMAGE -->

      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <!-- PICTURE 4 FADE OUT -->

        <img id="aerateConcrete" src="imgs/aeratedConcrete.jpg" alt="aerateConcrete" class="imgBorder" style="width:50%; display: none;">

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END OF PICTURE ROW AFTER CLICK -->

  </div>
  <!-- END CONTAINER OF 1st LAYER PICTURES DIV -->

  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->

  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->
  <!-- START OF 3RD LAYER FOR KILO SPECIFICATION PICTURES -->

</body>
```

Click on picture to Fade-Out and then get 4 more picture Fade-In automatically after click

Comment: I am sorry. Am just learning on my own WebDesign so I try and learn. Thank you so much for caring answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple issues with your code. Try subdivising your work into steps, since it'll be easier for you to progress, and for us to help you.

Here is my attempt to put it back in the right direction :

```js
//with proper html class and ids, and multiple instructions in one function, you can greatly reduce the size of your js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".pulse-button").click(function() {
    //BUTTON FADEOUT AND DISABLE
    $(this).addClass('fadeOut');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    //SHOW MAIN CATEGORIE
    $("#mainCategorie").fadeToggle("slow", "linear", "complete");

  });
  
  $("#mainCategorie img").click(function() {
    //HIDE MAIN CATEGORIE
    //$("#mainCategorie").fadeOut(300);
    //HIDE ALL IMAGES BUT NOT THE ONE CLICKED
    //$("#mainCategorie img").not(this).fadeOut(300);
    //SHOW KILO SPECIFICATION
    $("#kiloSpecification").fadeIn(300);
  });

});
```

```css
/*as for the css simpler is better, first make something working like you want and only after that make it good-looking.*/
/*I removed what was in the way. I'm not using bootstrap so I may have missed some good practice there.*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pulse-button {
  transition: all .5s linear;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(232, 76, 61, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e84c3d;
  color: white;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -ms-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.pulse-button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
  }
}


/* BACKGROUND */

.hero-image {
  background: url(imgs/sajad-mohammadi-1159479-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  !important position: relative;
}


/*----------*/

.column {
  width: 25%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.column img{
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  height:50px;
}
/*if you want some img to have specific proportions, add them here like so :
#plasterBoard{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
*/


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.imgBorder {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--try to only include scripts you need, including multiple jquery instance could create bugs-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--your style and js goes here-->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <!--in the html, use div to group content as you need it : in your case you need at least a div for the start, a div for the "main category", and a div for the "kilo selection"-->
  <!-- START BUTTON -->
  <div>
    <button id="pulseButton" class="pulse-button" class="container" style="align-content: center; outline: none;">
      <h1>START</h1>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- END START BUTTON -->

  <!-- MAIN CATEGORY SELECTION -->
  <div id="mainCategorie" style="display:none;" class="hero-image">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="column">
        <img id="plasterBoard" src="imgs/Plasterboard.jpeg" alt="plasterboard" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="brick" src="imgs/brick.jpeg" alt="brick" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="concreteStone" src="imgs/concrete(stone).jpeg" alt="concreteStone" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="aerateConcrete" src="imgs/aeratedConcrete.jpg" alt="aerateConcrete" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END MAIN CATEGORY SELECTION -->

  <!-- KILO SPECIFICATION SELECTION -->
  <div id="kiloSpecification" style="display:none;" class="hero-image">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="column">
        <img id="kilosIcon10" src="imgs/10kilo.png" alt="10kilo" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="kilosIcon20" src="imgs/20kilo.png" alt="20kilo" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="kilosIcon30" src="imgs/30kilo.png" alt="30kilo" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img id="kilosIcon40" src="imgs/40kilo.png" alt="40kilo" class="imgBorder">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

There was much to say but I tried to keep it at the minimum and to show the rest in the code. If you need me to expand on something don't hesitate to ask, but again try going step by step : there is much for you to learn and many questions you'll have are already answered here on SO.

As a good rule of thumb, try to start with the html ("ok, I want 4 rows of 4 images in my page") then the basic css ("I want my images to be side by side") then the js ("now, I want my images to only appear when start is clicked") and only after all that the advanced css ("I want blinking and rotating images !").

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you very much for you help as also for caring. Although I want the images of the "material (concrete, brick etc)" to fade out and then the Kilos pictures to occur so the client chooses the weight and then I will put more pictures depending their choices. Lots of respect,
Rafail

Comment: I wasn't sure of what you wanted, and I'm still unsure (^^) so I added 2 possibilities for you to try (just uncomment the line you want in the JS). You could have found the first one on your own so once again take your time, try to understand how it work or you'll never get to the end.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I got it from your help! <3

Comment: You're welcome ! Well done and I'm glad I helped ^^